# Bootstrap tooltip and replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following element:

```
<a class="btn btn-default clickaction" title="ACTIVE">X</a>
```

And for this, I have bootstrap tooltip enabled:

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[title]'
});
```

I added an on-click listener:

```
$("body").on("click", ".clickaction", function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<a class="btn btn-default clickaction" title="INACTIVE">Y</a>');
});
```

If the user hovers over the button X, he sees the tooltip ACTIVE. If he clicks on it (and doesn't move his mouse from the button), the button is replaced with the new button Y as expected, but the old tooltip doesn't disapear.

See http://www.bootply.com/PNr4TFszVP

How to fix this?

Comment: It was a simplified example. In my real situation, I have some other classes and data-Attributes (with bound js-events) on this button, so I would also have to remove/change all the classes and data-attributes, add the new ones, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinitiate the tooltip when making your replacement:

```
$("body").on("click", ".clickaction", function(){
    $(this).tooltip('destroy')
           .replaceWith('<a class="btn btn-default clickaction" title="INACTIVE">Y</a>');
});
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/TnHBm2KscT)

Comment: Ok, thats the solution! But its enough to "destroy" the the tooltip, since the re-initalisation of it is done by $('body').tooltip({    selector: '[title]' });